# Error installing Oracle-Java6

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, oracle, java

I'm attempting to install Oracle-Java6 on my VPS, running ubuntu-10.04 for the purpose of running Openmeetings.  I installed the ppa webupd8team/java, updated and ran sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer.  At the end of the installation, I am presented with the following error message

> Creating jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar
>   Killed
>   ERROR: Failed to unpack JAR file:
>
> > > jre/lib/rt.jar
>
> Installation failed. Please refer to the Troubleshooting Section of
>   the Installation Instructions on the download page.
>   cannot unpack jdk6
>   Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.
>   dpkg: error processing oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    oracle-java6-installer
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've tried running sudo apt-get -f install to see if that helps but am presented with the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We usually (read: always) install java from the packages available on the oracle website instead of the OS package manager. `mkdir /usr/local/jdk-1.6.xxx/ ; tar -xzvf /tmp/jdk-1.6.xxx /usr/local/jdk-1.6.xxx ;` tends to be easier and more stable for us.

Comment: @lVlint67: & how do you update those packages later, just removing these directories & repeating the process for newer version ? but I what's the issue in installing through webupd8 ppa ?

Answer (score 0):

Much prefer to install JDK using the ff:

Download package on the oracle official repo

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads

then put the package on your prefer location e.g /opt/java

then change access permission by typing:

sudo chmod 775 jdk-6u45-linux-i586.bin

then extract the package:

sudo ./jdk-6u45-linux-arch.bin

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I actually ended up upgrading my server's operating system to Ubuntu 12.04, then no problem.  Thanks for the response though.